# Vaadin 23: startup fails with "TypeError: cli.isMultipleCompiler is not a function"

Tags: node.js, vaadin23, webpack-cli

I have a project with Vaadin 23.0.8 that fails to start with the error message "cli.isMultipleCompiler is not a function". It seems to be a compatibility problem with webpack-cli Version 4.9.2 which needs to be upgraded to 4.10.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a know issue and fixed with 23.1.1 and 22.0.17

https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/13952

Answer (score 0):

On Linux/MacOS: To upgrade a node-package inside of a Vaadin project, go to your project directory. This is what you need to do to execute `npm` for your Vaadin project:

```bash
# Link the node executable to your project directory
ln -s ~/.vaadin/node/node node

# Do the same with npm
ln -s ~/.vaadin/node/node_modules/npm/bin/npm npm
```

Now you can use `npm` for your project, eg. to upgrade webpack to version 4.10.0:

```
./npm install webpack-cli@4.10.0
```